# Started paging before reaching max size in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

Paging started before reaching max size configured in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 version.

```
2021-05-31 08:59:30,293 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222038: Starting paging on address 'consumer_queue'; size is currently: 208,250 bytes; max-size-bytes: 524,288,000; global-size-bytes: 1,073,744,320
```

Address settings configured for queue `consumer_queue`.

```xml
<address-setting match="consumer_queue">
    <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
    <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
    <max-size-bytes>500Mb</max-size-bytes>
    <page-size-bytes>10Mb</page-size-bytes>
    <max-delivery-attempts>5</max-delivery-attempts>
    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
    <auto-create-queues>false</auto-create-queues>
    <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
    <auto-create-jms-queues>false</auto-create-jms-queues>
    <auto-create-jms-topics>false</auto-create-jms-topics>
</address-setting>
```

`global-max-size` set as `-1`. The JVM is using `-Xms36G` and the broker is automatically configuring the `global-max-size` to 18G, confirmed via this log:

```
AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 19,327,352,832
```

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it may be a bug. Please file an issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARTEMIS), and include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Actually configured heap size as ```36G``` considering application volume and traffic. Also I set the max memory per specific address and expect paging should start after reaching that configured value. Most of the time I noticed current size and max size almost same when paging start.

Comment: Can you verify that the `global-max-size` is being set as you expect by inspecting the logging that I referenced in my answer?

Comment: During Artemis start, found the following lines ```AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 19,327,352,832 ```. Which means 19Gb.

Comment: To be clear, 19,327,352,832 is actually 18GB (i.e. 18 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024).

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the all the new information you've provided.

Comment: Did you ever file an issue for this?